# Getting data from a remote XML file in Appcelerator titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to parse a very simple XML file.

I need to get one tag element that contains a URL.
The tag in the XML file is sURL.

I have tried using the code below but its not returning the text value of the URL.
I don't know what i'm doing wrong and why it's not working.

```
var url = "http://example.com/data.xml"; //xml resource url     
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function() {   
  var doc = this.responseXML.documentElement;
  var myURL = doc.getElementsByTagName("sURL");
  Ti.API.info(myURL);
};
xhr.onerror = function(e) { 
 alert('Network error '+e.error);
};
xhr.open('GET',url);
xhr.send();
```

XML :

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>test</title>
<description>

</description>
<time>test</time>
<time2>test</time2>
<sURL>https://example.com</sURL>
<item>
<title>test</title>
<broadcast>test</broadcast>
<time>17:00</time>
<time2>14:00</time2>
</item>
<item>
<title>test</title>
<broadcast>test</broadcast>
<time>19:00</time>
<time2>16:00</time2>
</item>
<item>
<title>test</title>
<broadcast>test</broadcast>
<time>21:00</time>
<time2>18:00</time2>
</item>
<item>
<title>test</title>
<broadcast>test</broadcast>
<time>23:00</time>
<time2>20:00</time2>
</item>
<item>
<title>test</title>
<broadcast/>
<time>01:00</time>
<time2>22:00</time2>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: can you add the relevant xml section?

Comment: <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
    <title>test</title>
    <description>
</description>
<time>test</time>
<time2>GMT</time2>
<sURL>https://example.como</sURL>
<item>
<title>test title</title>
<broadcast>test</broadcast>
<time>17:00</time>
<time2>14:00</time2>
</item>

Comment: I have added the XML code above.

Answer (score 1):

check the below code to get the first item of sURL, if it didn't work share the xml file

```
var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kassemitani/e25ab8654a4914a7e19edaecd7cb5460/raw/3aad56a246edc8e4dd42b1255c602f8676434a8f/test.xml"; //xml resource url     
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function() {   
  var doc = this.responseXML.documentElement;
  var myURL = doc.getElementsByTagName("sURL").item(0).textContent;
  Ti.API.info(myURL);
};
xhr.onerror = function(e) { 
 alert('Network error '+e.error);
};
xhr.open('GET',url);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i to get the the sURL tag from the following XML :

Comment: i get undefined from the output of Ti.API.info(myURL)

Comment: @Al1nuX i have tested the above code and it is working, it printed  https://example.com

Comment: @Al1nuX i hosted ur xml file use this link https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kassemitani/e25ab8654a4914a7e19edaecd7cb5460/raw/3aad56a246edc8e4dd42b1255c602f8676434a8f/test.xml

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply bro. but i still get [INFO] :   undefined , i'm using Alloy and the latest SDK. i don't know why i cant see the text result.

Comment: I've tried it on Android and I have to use `var myURL = doc.getElementsByTagName("sURL").item(0).textContent;` to get the text. Check http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.XML.Node for more properties.

Comment: thx @miga i have updated the answer, i was testing on iPhone and text was working

Comment: Nice! I've added a JIRA ticket to update the "Working with XML Data" documentation in the Appc docs so it will reflect the changes, too!